# Auto complete in comments

Tags: feature-request

When we want to notify another user in a comment and start typing @USER_NAME it pops up a suggestion box and displays the complete name. Is it possible to enhance this by completing full user name when Enter key is hit ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is what happens when you click the tab key: The username is completed where you are writing.

[image: before]

[image: after]

In a comment, the enter key is already used to write the comment, and it would create problems.

Comment: It would have been better if event was linked to Enter Key.